# Make errors when using external commands

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make, pylint

I have a Makefile in my python project. I am getting issues when trying to build the target **lint** which is configured as:

```
lint:
    pylint -j0 --ignore=src/_playground --extension-pkg-whitelist=gurobipy src/
    mypy --exclude src/_playground/ src/
    flake8 --exclude=src/_playground src/
```

When I run the make to build the target **lint**, I end up with the following error message,

```bash
------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.94/10 (previous run: 9.94/10, +0.00)

make: *** [Makefile:79: lint] Error 12
```

*Line: 79 corresponds to the `pylint` line in the Makefile.*

I am able to sucessfully run, all the individual commands by itself i.e. 'pylint', 'mypy' & 'flake8' commands for the **lint** target.

Can you point to how can i debug to understand whats happening when trying to execute the commands from `make` ?

I can't get rid of this as its part of *github* actions on my repo.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  You ran pylint, and pylint will exit with a success code if there are zero issues in your code, and a non-success code if there are any issues in your code.  You can see from the output that your code has some issues, because it's only 9.94 out of 10, not 10 out of 10.  So pylint exits with a non-success code and so make reports that to you.  If you want this to pass, you must fix all the issues in your code so pylint finds no errors.  If you don't want it to fail even if there are errors, tell make that by prepending the pylint command with `-`.

Comment: Try reading this: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html

Answer (score 0):

As explained by MadScientist in the comment, pylint exited with [error code 12, it means you have warning message (4) and refactor messages (8) raised](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/run.html#exit-codes). You have to fix your python code, not the makefile, nor the github actions, to make pylint happy.